# Cartesian half-square of a list

Tags: f#, cartesian-product

The question of how to generate the Cartesian product of a list with itself in F# is a familiar one, but I need something slightly different: *half* of the resulting square. That is, [1; 2; 3] -> [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)].

The most obvious ways to do it involve nested for loops with integer indexes, but what's the most idiomatic way to do it in F#? I'm not concerned about performance, just simplicity and elegance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure but I think you want something like this:

```
let pairs = function
   | [] -> [] 
   | (x::xs) -> List.map (fun x' -> (x,x')) xs

let rec hSquare xs =                        
   match xs with                           
   | [] -> []                              
   | (_::ys) -> pairs xs @ hSquare ys
```

with `hSquare` you get for example:

```
> hSquare [1..3];;
val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (1, 3); (2, 3)]
> hSquare [1..4];;
val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); (2, 3); (2, 4); (3, 4)]
```

which includes your example

### remarks

- This surely is not some half of the usual cartesian product (that would be `[(1,1);(1,2);(1,3);(2,1);(2,2);(2,3);(3,1);(3,2);(3,3)]` in your case
- I did not care about performance, tailcalls, whatsoever here - you can surely improve on this.
- I just wanted to know if you are looking for this and it's to big for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the obligatory alternative based on [Carsten König's exploratory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924079/cartesian-half-square-of-a-list/29924423#29924423): one may also use a [Sequence Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) to achieve these results.

```
let c2 args = seq{
    let argsi = Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i, x) args 
    for (i, x) in argsi do
        for (j, y) in argsi do
            if i < j then yield (x, y) }

c2 [1..3]   // val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(1, 2); (1, 3); (2, 3)]
```